# Data Binding - Failed to copy full contents

Tags: android, android-databinding

My app has a structure with many modules. When I'm building the app I usually get this error and I cannot determine why...

```
Failed to copy full contents from 
'D:\Projects\MyCompanyName\myproject\build\myproject\module1\intermediates\data_binding_base_class_log_artifact\debug\out\com.mycompanyname.myproject-binding_classes.json' 
to 
'D:\Projects\MyCompanyName\myproject\build\myproject\module2\intermediates\data_binding_base_class_logs_dependency_artifacts\debug\out\com.mycompanyname.myproject-binding_classes.json'
```

This happen with different modules. Before, the project was built normally when I relaunched it 2-3 times. But with more modules this error started to appear more often. I've even tried to change a build directory:

```
allprojects {
    buildDir = rootProject.buildDir.path + "/${project.name}"
}
```

But it didn't help :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the reason. In my project Gradle, I have a code that applies some common values in modules' Gradle files. 
Besides everything I was enabling data binding there:

```
afterEvaluate { project ->
    if (project.hasProperty('android')) {
        android {
            dataBinding {
                enabled = true
            }

            // Other stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

But not every module had data binding implemented (especially persistence layer modules). So, the answer is that you should put the line to enable data binding only in those modules, where data binding is implemented, and in the app module.

Comment: The answer rather is, not to configure it in such a strange way - but statically.

Comment: @MartinZeitler is there a better non-strange way to configure common properties in modules' Gradle files? If there are, for example, more than 20 modules, configure everything statically is not a decision. However, now I see that the data binding we still need to configure separately for each module.

Comment: Data-binding is not a common property - if you only can have 1 application module; libraries might also use it, but only when there is front-end code - so theoretically, you might even apply it, where it isn't needed.

Comment: @MartinZeitler but you can have as many UI modules with activities and fragments as you want. And you need to enable Data-binding in each of them.

Comment: Then enable it for the ones that use it.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, clicking on `Build` and then `Clean Project` on Android Studio solved the problem.